# Convert XML column to Table Data in SQL Query

Tags: sql, xml, web-services, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have this XML file which is a returned data table from web service:

```
        DECLARE @MyXML XML = 
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
            <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Blah" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="Blah">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Col1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:schema>
          <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
            <DocumentElement xmlns="">
              <Blah diffgr:id="Blah1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                <Col1>testing1</Col1>
              </Blah>
            </DocumentElement>
          </diffgr:diffgram>
        </DataTable>'
```

I want an output like this:
   Select Col1

Col1

---

testing1

Then, I would be able to insert the data into a table in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this XML under your control?

I'm especially irritated by this

```
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
```

This line is redefining the default namespace.

The XML you show consists of a schema portion and a data portion

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

    <!-- This schema is describing your data''s structure -->

    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Blah" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Blah">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Col1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>

    <!-- End of schema -->
    <!-- Begin of data -->

    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
        <Blah diffgr:id="Blah1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <Col1>testing1</Col1>
        </Blah>
    </DocumentElement>
    </diffgr:diffgram>

    <!-- End of data -->

</DataTable>';
```

Your statement

> Then, I would be able to insert the data into a table in sql.

... let's me think, that the *real-world* use case will consist of more than one column. In this case you do not show enough.

This query would read just the `<Col1>` content in a lazy approach:

```
SELECT @MyXML.value('(//*:Col1/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

In general it is good to be as specific as possible, but the actual issue looks, as if you might be better off with a namespace wildcard and a *deep search (`//`)* down to `<DocumentElement>`:

```
SELECT de.query('.')
FROM @MyXml.nodes('//DocumentElement') A(de)
```

This query will return various content of this area:

```
SELECT de.value('(Blah/@*:id)[1]','nvarchar(max)') DiffGr_ID
      ,de.value('(Blah/@*:rowOrder)[1]','int') MsData_RowOrder
      ,de.value('(Blah/@*:hasChanges)[1]','nvarchar(max)') diffgr_HasChanges
      ,de.value('(Blah/Col1/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') Col1_Text
FROM @MyXml.nodes('//DocumentElement') A(de);
```

The result

```
DiffGr_ID   MsData_RowOrder diffgr_HasChanges   Col1_Text
-----------------------------------------------------------
Blah1       0               inserted            testing1
```

Comment: I checked the tick. Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me about this question? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719134/how-i-can-insert-jason-web-service-data-into-a-sql-table-using-sql-query
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO sampletable
    (
        col1,
        col2
    )
    SELECT
        t.value('(col1/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') ---colum name of the xml
        t.value('(col2/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') ---colum name of the xml
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('/NewDataSet/MYTABLE') AS TempTable(t)
```

take not ,when the type of the column in the xml is float you need to change the 'narchar(10)' to 'float', or if date use 'date', etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the XML Namespace before using the XQuery:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://tempuri.org/' AS ns, 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' AS dg)

SELECT
    Col1 = XC.value('(Col1)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @MyXML.nodes('/ns:DataTable/dg:diffgram/DocumentElement/Blah') AS XT(XC)
```